# What is the relationship between "c" and "G"

Tags: general-relativity

I am working on relativity equations and I need help on this

This is assuming $c$ could be calculated from $G$

Can we write $c$ in terms of $G$ in $e=mc^2$

Has anyone tried to unify them?

I mean both "determine" mass

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *both "determine" mass*?

Answer (score 3):

$c$ and $G$ are two different fundamental constants of nature. Neither can be written in terms of the other in any meaningful way. In other words, knowing the value of $c$ tells us nothing about the value of $G$, and vice-versa.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110476/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-what-is-the-relationship-between-c-and-g).